# Closing Parent From the FormClosing event in child

Tags: .net, winforms

Is it possible to close the parent form in the FormClosing event from the child?

Will that raise errors since the `Close()` of the parent will try to close the child again...

I'll update the question since someone downvoted it. I'm using progress (OpenEdge) together with .NET. If I have a construction like this where the child form tries to close the parent form, I'm getting a huge Progress error. I was wondering if in a pure .NET WinForms application this would be a problem.

Comment: Assuming you can't have the child as a dialog and pass back a cancel result to ask it to close maybe when opening the form pass a reference to a boolean that indicates to the parent it should close as soon as possible?

Comment: Well, yeah, indeed, but let's just say there's a lot of code that's been there for years which I just cannot alter in a couple of days.

Comment: Yes, this won't work well, the form's isn't closed yet when the FormClosing event runs.  Have the parent subscribe the child's FormClosed event instead.

Answer (score 0):

What if you remove the child first, the child can be removed from its parent by using :

```
' Remove child from parent
    Dim p As Form = myChild.Parent
    p.Children.Remove(myChild)
```

Comment: Because at that moment, I don't know yet if the parent can be removed... What I'm currently looking at is canceling the FormClosing event and delaying it until later...